# How to resolve the problem that Alt+Tab switch preview disappeared?

Tags: unity, window

**Affected system:**
Ubuntu Unity 16.04.

**Problem:** Pressing Alt+Tab no longer shows the [preview window](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/T7vj7AV7Fjo/maxresdefault.jpg)

**Question:** How can I trace back the problem to submit a proficient bug report?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A silly temporary fix is to switch to the desktop from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>  by guessing first and then it will reappear in front of apps when you ,<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it again. Of course, that does not fend off the possibility of it disappearing again.

Another permanent fix: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211863, but it changes the window manager.

I could not find something more meaningful. Hope it helps

Comment: So, are you telling that the ALT+TAB sometimes gets trapped in another desktop? I tried that in every desktop until it worked, your answer helped me one way or another jaja